# Avoid nested transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactional, propagation

Below is structure of my method:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public methodOuter(){
      //some processing
      methodInner1();
      methodInner2();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public methodInner1(){
    //save something to db
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public methodInner2(){
    //some processing
    //throws exception
    }
```

Scenario is `methodInner1()` is processed successfully but `methodInner2()` throws exception. So i want to rollback commit done in `methodInner1()`. Currently commit in `methodInner1()` is not getting rolled back. I want `methodOuter()` to be in single transaction

Comment: There are different transaction modes that you can leverage here. I guess what you need is use existing else create new

Comment: You can use `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` on both `methodInner1()` and `methodInner2()` this will make all the methods to be executed in a single transaction.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the type of the thrown exception (lets assume its a NPE) you could try something like

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackOn=NullPointerException.class)
public methodOuter(){
  //some processing
  methodInner1();
  methodInner2();
}

@Override
public methodInner1(){
  //save something to db
}

@Override
public methodInner2(){
  //some processing
  //throws exception
}
```

In that case you don't need to annotate the "Inner" functions. methodOuter will be rolled back if NullPointerException is thrown. If you want to Rollback for every possible Exception you should change the annotation to

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn=Exception.class)
```

By the way: RuntimeExceptions will cause a rollback whether they are annotated or not.